# Comparing iterated string to single-char string

Tags: c++, string, char, comparison

I'm trying to make a simple program for my college class that is supposed to split a given string (target) into a string vector based on a delimiter within the string (delimiter). I am currently trying to iterate through the target variable and find if that specific char within the string equals the char within the delimiter string. I know that changing the delimiter variable to a char in the first place would make this much easier, but my professor wants the delimiter variable to be a string and I'm not sure why. I keep getting this error:

main.cpp:18:21: error: no match for ‘operator==’ (operand types are ‘char’ and ‘std::string {aka std::basic_string}’)

Here's what I have so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

vector <string> split(string target, string delimiter) {
    vector <string> splitString;
    splitString.reserve(target.length());     
    
    for(int i=0; i<target.length(); i++) {
        
       if(target[i] == delimiter) { //problem originates from this line
            continue;
        }
        else {
            splitString[i] += target[i];
        }
    }
    
    return splitString;
}

int main() {
    vector <string> displayString;
    displayString = split("10,20,30", ",");
    
    for(int i=0; i<displayString.size(); i++) {
        cout << displayString[i] << " ";
    }
 
}
```

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There is no such [operator defined](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_cmp), the compiler is right. What's your question?

Comment: [`std::string::find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) would be the easier way

Comment: `target[i]` is a character. A lonely `char`. if you need to compare  against at delimiter that is a string, you'll have to iterate through the delimiter string as well. For all you know there will be multiple characters in the delimiter. Try multiple loops. The outer loop works it's way through `target` character by character . The inner loop works through `target` and `delimiter`. If the inner loop finds a complete match, store the token preceding the delimiter in the `vector`. If not, advance the outer loop by one and start the inner loop over again from where outer points.

Comment: Note: The above's not particularly fast, but it's simple and will get you started.

Comment: What do you expect `target[i] == delimiter` to do? On the left is a character; on the right a string. You can compare two strings. You can compare two characters. What should it mean to compare a single character to an entire string? Why did you pick a single character out of `target` but not pick one out of `delimiter`?

Comment: I changed delimiter to delimiter[0] (It's supposed to be a single char out of the string, dumb ik) and now I'm getting a segmentation fault

Comment: What if the delimiters are one character but the instructor wants to be able to split on multiple delimiters? Eg, `','` and `'.'`?

Comment: @JustinMcCown A segmentation fault would be a new problem, hence worthy of a new question.

Answer (score 0):

## Problems

Comparing `string` to `char`. Asker solved this on their own.

```
splitString.reserve(target.length());
```

reserves storage but doesn't do anything with it. It just allocates the space. This means

```
splitString[i] += target[i];
```

writes to a string that hasn't been initialized yet. This is likely the reported crash. Should have used

```
splitString.resize(target.length());
```

`resize` grabs space and initializes it. But... probably WAY too much space once you resolve the next problem.

`splitString[i] += target[i];` inside a loop on `i` effectively copies the characters in `target` one by one into the `string`s in `splitString`. You want to accumulate that characters between delimiters and store the accumulation in `splitString`.

## Solution

```cpp
vector<string> split(string target, string delimiter)
{
    vector<string> splitString;
    string acumulator;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < target.length(); i++)
    {

        if (target[i] == delimiter[0]) // please check this with the 
                                       // instructor. They are crafty.
                                       // there could be some subtext 
                                       // you have missed
        {
            splitString.push_back(acumulator); // store accumulation
            acumulator = ""; // restart accumulating
        }
        else
        {
            acumulator += target[i]; // accumulate
        }
    }
    splitString.push_back(acumulator); // store whatever is left
    return splitString;
}
```